# Getting undefined error when tried to access loop variables from ngOnInit() in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

**In the ngOnInit() function I receive data from a service for use throughout the rest of my component.It is undefined anywhere outside of the subscribe. I'm not sure why.**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Renderer2, HostListener,ViewChild, TemplateRef, Inject} from '@angular/core';
    import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
    import { NgbModalOptions, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pattern',
  templateUrl: './pattern.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pattern.component.scss']
})

export class PatternComponent implements OnInit {


  public config: any = {};

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any,private modal: NgbModal,private pattern:patternService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

   this.pattern.Pattern(this.local).subscribe(
      data => {

      for (var i = 0; i < this.length1; i++){
         this.visitedArray[temp1] = [false, this.Patternarray[i]]; //I'm trying to access this in onselect() function. If the value is false I'm trying to do something
         console.log("Visited Array ng:",this.visitedArray[temp1]);
        }
       },
      err => {
        console.error(err);
      }
    );
 }
}
```

**This is my onselect() function where I try to access (this.visitedArray[this.temp1]) from ngOnit, but not able to access that. 'Visited Array:' undefined is printed in console**

```
onselect(row, i) {

      console.log("Visited Array:",this.visitedArray[this.temp1]);
       console.log("visited id:",this.visitedArray[this.temp1][0]);

    }
```

Comment: Subscribing to an observable is an asynchronous pattern. You need to call the `onselect()` only after the data has been assigned to `this.visitedArray` variable. That can be assured only if you call the `onselect()` function inside the subscription after the `this.visitedArray` variable is assigned values.

Answer (score 1):

here the service call is asynchronous so the code outside `subscribe` will be executed first and the code inside subscribe will be executed once the service returns data(which might take time). therefore you are trying to access a variable before it gets its value(i.ie inside subscribe) which gives undefined.

The solution would be start processing your data once it arrives(i.e. inside `subscribe`)

Answer (score 1):

In short words simply do this:

```
this.pattern.Pattern(this.local).subscribe(
      data => {
      this.length1 = this.patterns.length;
      this.visited_count=this.length1-1;
     for (var i = 0; i < this.length1; i++) {
          this.Patternarray[i] = this.questions[i].Id;}
     for (var i = 0; i < this.length1; i++){
         this.visitedArray[temp1] = [false, this.Patternarray[i]]; //I'm trying to access this in onselect() function. If the value is false I'm trying to do something
         console.log("Visited Array ng:",this.visitedArray[temp1]);
        }
onselect(row,i); // call onselect from here
       },
      err => {
        console.error(err);
      }
    );
```